# Why am I getting Error keyNotFound when I try to public a Pull Request in XCode13

Tags: swift, xcode, pull-request

Not sure why this happened:

I am trying to create a pull request in Xcode and this error is coming up. It has worked in the past and this is the first time I'm getting this error.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP9W0.png)

[screenshot of error (2nd half)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07QJS.png)

Comment: The decoder doesn't find a correspondence to key "data". But it's ***really*** hard to guess if you don't provide at least a sample of your code, with the JSON received and the model you are using. It might help following these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Same issue. Tried to change my github login with new token etc. still see this issue. This used to work for me and nothing changed on my account, one day it just started giving me this error. For now I will just not use this Xcode feature.

Comment: Having same issue, just created a new repository, sited up account Github with Xcode, after committing and pushing (successfully), created new all request
but got same error on publishing the pull request